# jquery datepicker dynamic with personal format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'd want to applhy at dynamic element datepicker with a custom format.
I have tried this but doesn't work, no error in console:

```
    var arr_month = new Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');

    $( "#check-out").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy',
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    });

    $(document).on('focus',".date-input", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var myDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        var prettyDate =(myDate.getDate()) + '/' + (myDate.getMonth()+1);
        var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-M', myDate, {monthNamesShort: arr_month});
        $(this).val(formattedDate);
    });
```

Ii I put only works fine! :

```
$(document).on('focus',".date-input", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

The code is inside `document.ready`

How can I apply custom format to dynamic element to datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're trying to show a date in another field formatted differently from what you see in your datepicker.

Did you try using datepicker's `altField` and `altFormat` properties, as described [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field)?

You should be able to specify a selector identifying the other fields you want to populate upon datepicker selection and a different format for them.